# How to remove one of the data from output nodejs mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, postman

actually, i want to change some data in result like add one row and remove one row from return json

here is the code

```
const Ledgers = db.Ledgers;
const LedgersSync = db.LedgersSync;

      const ledgerList=await Ledgers.find(queryObj)
    
        queryObj["isTransfer"] = 0
        const ledgerListSync=await LedgersSync.find(queryObj)
        
        console.log('ledgerList',ledgerList)
        console.log('ledgerListSync',ledgerListSync)
        
        Array.prototype.push.apply(ledgerList,ledgerListSync);
        return ledgerList
```

**result i get**

```
{
    "_id": "608bb0725cdd5f0c93d96da0",
    "companyId": 294989,
    "company_id": "60741775b9808d1d885e66d5",
    "Name": "ABC Company",
    "reservedName": "",
    "uid": "4eb25490-8288-4841-a925-ed2512ad6d7b-000000c4",

}
```

**result i want**

```
{
    "_id": "608bb0725cdd5f0c93d96da0",
     "new":test
}
```

add new row and remove existing rows...

Comment: you want to remove a document (you call it "row") from mongo?

Comment: document data... want to edit

Comment: so you want to edit data in mongodb? you should use updateOne()

Comment: no just want display output like i have mention in question....
i want to edit returning json only

Comment: so search for 'projection' https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/ and please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const ledgerList=await Ledgers.find(queryObj)

    queryObj["isTransfer"] = 0
    const ledgerListSync=await LedgersSync.find(queryObj)
    
    console.log('ledgerList',ledgerList)
    console.log('ledgerListSync',ledgerListSync)
    
    Array.prototype.push.apply(ledgerList,ledgerListSync);
    return {"_id":ledgerList ["_id"],  "new":ledgerList["new"]}
```

just return that two fields!

Comment: @Piyush what does ledgerList  contains ,

Comment: it contain collection of mongodb in json for example you can see in question "result i get" line

Comment: @Piyush ledgerList is an object or array ?

Comment: ledgerList  is array

Comment: how are you creating the json object from that list please show that line of code

Comment: it will return json in postman this code is for api cration... check updated question

Comment: @Piyush how are you returning the json object in the api code

Comment: i have already share the code check it (editd answer)

Comment: i cant see any changes , its the same old

Comment: return ledgerList  please add details on what are you doing with this return array

Comment: ohh!! ok forgot question now, this is code "return await Ledgers.find(queryObj)" i want add new field in it(it will return josn ex. {
    "_id": "608bb0725cdd5f0c93d96da0"} )